# Triggering single Azure Function using multiple Azure Queues

Tags: azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-queues

I want to trigger single Azure Function on adding message in Multiple Azure Queues.

As well, is it possible to trigger Azure Function on some conditions? Like if Azure Queue Message has `type` property as `TYPE_1` then only it should trigger the function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to [create a function that is triggered when messages are submitted to an Azure Storage queue.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function)

This article explains how to work with [Azure Queue storage bindings in Azure Functions. Azure Functions supports trigger and output bindings for queues.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue)

The portal provides a UI for this configuration, but you can edit the file directly by opening the Advanced editor available via the Integrate tab of your function.

In .NET, the parameter type defines the data type for input data. For instance, use string to bind to the text of a queue trigger, a byte array to read as binary and a custom type to de-serialize to an object.

For languages that are dynamically typed such as JavaScript, use the dataType property in the function.json file. For example, to read the content of an HTTP request in binary format, set dataType to binary:

```html
JSON

Copy
{
    "dataType": "binary",
    "type": "httpTrigger",
    "name": "req",
    "direction": "in"
}
```

In this article you learn the high-level concepts surrounding [functions triggers and bindings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings)

Kindly let me know if you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. "Multiple Azure Queues"